# Is this edit ok?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Carrier phone system adaptation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/15697/carrier-phone-system-adaptation)

Are theses edits sufficient to open this question.

Comment: Please do not post multiple meta questions about one topic. If an issue needs moderator attention, the best thing to do is to **flag** the question. That said, I've reopened your question on account of it being clear enough what you're asking now.